# How to make a List within a List?

Tags: android, list, listview, flutter, dart

I'm trying to add a List within a List of ExpansionTiles, but I'm getting a bunch of errors when trying to create it. Can somebody help me?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 7, horizontal: 7),
      child: ExpansionTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.explore, color: this.colors[index]),
        title: RichText(text: title(firstSection[index], index)),
        trailing: Icon(
          Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
          color: this.colors[index],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
        initiallyExpanded: true,
        onExpansionChanged: (bool expanding) => setState(() => {this.colors[index] = (expanding) ? Colors.white : Colors.black}),
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: tiles[index].length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int indexx) {
              return tiles[index][indexx];
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
  itemCount: firstSection.length,
);
```

My list is like that: `List<List<CreateTiles>> tiles;`

I already checked and the problem is not at "CreateTiles" class but at my other listview inside ExpansionTile

Comment: What are "various errors"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you cant give unbounded height inside unbounded height, the first listview requires a specific height given by the children.

This can be fixed with setting `shrinkWrap = true` in the second (inner) listview.

Comment: Thank you! Now it is Solved. Didn't knew that I needed to add "shrinkWrap". Can you explain why I needed that?

Comment: Hey, sure! So the reason is because, "shrinkWrap" basically evaluates all the space that the child elements in the ListView will take up BEFORE rendering it, this is costly in performance and can be laggy with lots of elements, but since it knows the size, it can tell the parent list during render time exactly how much it needs. The name kinda fits, think of it like: it "shrinks" the infinite length list into the smallest size it can be for all elements to render right, and "wraps" it into one big element, and this element can now be properly given space in the parents space.

Answer (score 1):

Here example of Listview inside Listview

```
   ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 5,
    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 5,
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, j) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text("Item $i, $j"),
          );
        },
      );
    },
  )
```